# One Global Ktable Class and multiple KStream Classes in scala

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

is it possible One **Global KTable Class** all properties access by all other **kstreams classes** in **scala** ?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. What do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

> To query remote states for the entire app, you must expose the application’s full state to other applications, including applications that are running on different machines.

[Interactive Queries](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app)